# Android Drawable with fixed size element in center

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm trying to create a placeholder drawable, which should contain a animated image in the center. However, I'd like the center item to be of a fixed width and height. Is this doable?

This is the animated center image XML:

```
 <animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/loading"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"/>
```